# UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape is not triggering when view is rotated

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, rotation, uiinterfaceorientation

I am trying to make my app work in landscape orientation as well as portrait.  I have the proper methods installed in all my viewcontrollers and this code triggers when the ipad simulator is rotated, but always triggers portrait.  The landscape IF clause never gets triggered.  What could I be doing wrong?

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)InterfaceOrientation {
NSLog(@"******* ROTATING ******");
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation)) {

        NSLog(@"ROTATING View Landscape ******");

    } else    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)) {

        NSLog(@"ROTATING View Portrait ******");

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 5):

Device and interface orientation appear to be different things.  I found on Apple's site the way to do this using UIDeviceOrientation.  Using this test I get the proper triggers when i rotate the simulator and my ipad device.

```
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;

if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation))

{


}

else if (deviceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)

{

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I've found that the most reliable way to detect the current device orientation of an iPhone/iPad is to use the `statusBarOrientation` property, like so:

```
UIInterfaceOrientation currentOrientation = 
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
```

If you use that instead of `self.interfaceOrientation`, does your code work?

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I added the code and when I run it I see the same result.  Even with this method, the currentOrientation returns the orientation to be portrait even though I am staring at the simulator and the device is on its side.  Through a full 360 degree rotation the value is always coming back as portrait.

Comment: i also discovered that my info-plist file was updated for iphone and found the supported orientations array for ipad and updated them.  Reloaded the project and it is still only seeing portrait orientation.  I built my project on my ipad and rotated it and watched as all orientations trigger as portrait.

Comment: This solution is deprecated as of iOS 13

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code in swift for i:

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    let  deviceOrientation:UIDeviceOrientation = UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation

    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(deviceOrientation)){
        let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft.rawValue
        UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
    }
}
```

viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator: method above to figure out whether you are rotating to portrait or landscape.

my code basically changes the orientation back to landscape mode when portrait mode is detected.

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
+(bool)isLandscape
{
    return
        !UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait( [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation ) ||
        !UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait( [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation );
}
```

Comment: This answer and @Nungster's work in the simulator, but if the iPad is flat on a table, the device orientation is UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp or UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown. This will probably give an error, but can fail silently. Use the statusBarOrientation (@aroth's answer) to get the current state of the UI.